# Specifying when to return null and when to throw in fluent nHibernate based on ID

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We're working in a legacy code base that's got a pretty rough data model. Right now, we have a Object Mapping that looks like this:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;
using Validation.Domain;

namespace Validation.DomainMaps
{
    public sealed class BookMap : SubclassMap<Book>
   {
        public BookMap()
        {
            Map(x => x.Genre);

            References(x => x.Shelf, "ShelfId")
                .Nullable()
                .Not.LazyLoad()
                .NotFound.Ignore()
                .Cascade.All()
                .Fetch.Join();
        }
    }
}
```

In the application, a book without a shelf will have a ShelfId of 0. There is no row in the Shelf table with an Id of 0 and we are depending on nhibernate's `.NotFound.Ignore()` to return null which we'll check for and handle later on.

This has gotten us this far but, now we're trying to throw an exception when we try and access non-0 ShelfId's that don't have entries in the Shelf table.

Ideally, nhibernate would throw an exception only in the case that it could not find a Shelf with a non-0 Id and return null when asked for a Shelf with an Id of 0.

Any help would be exceptional!

Comment: I don't understand your question at all...

Comment: @Phill Maybe said a different way: I want to control nhibernate's not found behavior based on the Id I'm asking for. Imagine I have a table that has neither a row with Id 0 nor a row with Id 12. I want to control the NotFound behavior such that requesting Id 0 returns null but requesting Id 12 throws an exception.

The simple solution would be to leave the default NotFound behavior (throwing exception) and add a dummy row with Id of 0, but unfortunately we're not confident what in the app relies on getting null back when Id 0 is requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't perfect, but anyone looking to do this kind of thing should take a gander [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/01/28/how-to-use-0-instead-of-null-for-foreign-keys.aspx)